# Several images to add dynamically java?

Tags: java

I am doing a project on "online shopping" in java. NEED HELP:
If we click "clothes" button, a new frame will open and on that frame several images of different clothes will show up.HOW to do this?? 
Another thing is-There will be a "SEARCH" option where we can "search" between a price range.How to do this?
Clicking on a button will redirect u to a new frame where the images r already inserted! Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Post your attempt(codewise).

Comment: One of the method : Do ajax call for "search on price". On Ajax call get the list of images (i.e image src ) from the database . On success function it create new image element for all that sources.

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't understand the question properly, but i think you could populate the same frame with different results if you use Ajax. You could create a listener function for your button press or drop-down menus or checkbox etc. The listener function could return the required results to a particular section of your page.